# Query takes too much time for execution

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using Oracle 10g. The following query takes too much time:

```
  SELECT invno, invdate, ccode
    FROM acct
   WHERE     invno IS NOT NULL
         AND invdate > '01-Feb-2018'
         AND invno LIKE '%' || :ppassingmn.dept || '%'
         AND invno NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT (vdescript)
                             FROM genldgr
                            WHERE     vchrno LIKE 'IV%'
                                  AND trandate > '01-Feb-2018'
                                  AND vdescript LIKE
                                         '%' || :ppassingmn.dept || '%')
ORDER BY SUBSTR (invno, 12, 15);
```

Please optimize it.

Comment: You might want to add an execution plan.

Comment: I am not sure, may be you can try this. `with acct1 as
(select distinct (vdescript) vdescript
          from genldgr
         where vchrno like 'IV%'
           and trandate > '01-Feb-2018'
           and vdescript like '%' || :ppassingmn.dept || '%')
select invno, invdate, ccode
  from acct,acct1
 where acct.invno is not null
   and acct.invdate > '01-Feb-2018'
   and acct.invno like '%' || :ppassingmn.dept || '%'
   and acct.invno !=acct1.vdescript       
 order by substr(acct.invno, 12, 15);
`

Comment: Please add an execution plan to your question. Also, what is the datatype of the acct.invdate and genldgr.trandate columns? If they're dates, please convert your dates-as-strings into dates explicitly (e.g. `to_date('01/02/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`).

Comment: If `genldgr.vdescript` is defined as nullable, then try adding `where vdescript is not null` to the subquery, assuming that is your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much info. Query itself is pretty much useless (as if you called the mechanic and said "my blue car is slow. Why?").

Anyway, a few hints; maybe they'll help.

- `'01-Feb-2018'` is a string. If `INVDATE` is a `DATE` **datatype** column, you're forcing Oracle to perform implicit conversion between `VARCHAR2` and `DATE`. Use a date literal instead, e.g. `and invdate > date '2018-02-01'`. The same goes for `TRANDATE`.
- `LIKE` is slow. You use it twice. See if you can rewrite it to `invno = :passingmn.dept`. By the way, what is `:passingmn.dept`? Looks like a variable, but - what is that dot doing here? The same goes for `VDESCRIPT`.
- `DISTINCT` requires you to select all rows, and then remove duplicates. It seems that you don't really care about it, so - remove `DISTINCT`.
- As `INVNO` has to *look like* some parameter value, then it isn't `NULL` so you can probably remove `invno is not null` condition.
- `ORDER BY` also affects performance. Moreover, it selects a *substring*. Do you need it? If not, remove it
- are columns involved in the `WHERE` clause indexed? If not, do so

Finally, explain plan would help. Without it, people are partially blind.